# The mechanism of "FILTER NOT EXISTS" in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

Assuming the triples are following:

```
@prefix  :       <http://example/> .
@prefix  rdf:    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix  foaf:   <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .

:alice  rdf:type   foaf:Person .
:alice  foaf:name  "Alice" .
:bob    rdf:type   foaf:Person .
```

and then we perform 3 queries based on SPARQL 1.1:

Q1:

```
SELECT ?s 
WHERE 
{
    ?s ?p ?o .
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s foaf:name ?y }
}
```

Q2:

```
SELECT ?s 
WHERE 
{
    ?s ?p ?o .
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?x foaf:name ?y }
}
```

Q3:

```
SELECT ?s 
WHERE 
{
    ?s ?p ?o .
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?x foaf:mailbox ?y }
}
```

These three queries return three different solutions. Could anyone help me figure out why Q2 evaluates to no query solution in contrast to Q1 and Q3? Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: FYI: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#neg-example-1

Comment: yeah, this is the location where my doubts from so I made some examples to try to understand more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q2 returns no solution because in your data, there exists a statement that matches `?x foaf:name ?y`: `?x = :alice` and `?y = "Alice"`. You've put no further constraints on either `?x` or `?y`. So no matter what the other variables in your query (`?s`, `?p` and `?o`) are bound to, the `NOT EXISTS` condition will always fail  and therefore the query returns no result.

Comment: Great thanks for helping out! I think I understand with your instructions.

Comment: @JiantaoWu: I see that you are new on StackOverflow, please mark an answer as accepted if it solves your problem so that others don't waste time on questions that are already solved.